# How to fix ubuntu when recovery mode won't work and can't access windows?

Tags: boot, kernel, initramfs, recovery-mode

Basically, I can't run ubuntu or recovery mode either
_
[This shows up when I try to boot Ubuntu or recovery mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQLn8.jpg)
. I don't think it's a hardware problem, I used to run ubuntu every day on the very same device. Sadly I can't access Windows on my laptop, so that's a bit of a problem. It began when firefox started to lag my laptop. After some time of freezed desktop, I manually turned it off, and when I turned it on again, this began happening.
**I don't need to save the data from it or to make backups, everything valuable is in my main computer**.

Comment: Are you able to get to the GRUB menu? If so, try selecting an older kernel and see if it boots. If it does, then you've got a corrupt ramdisk file.

Comment: & do you have access to a Ubuntu usb iso to start a live usb session? You would at least be able (probably) to access everything on your system to back it up.

Comment: Probably severe disk damage after manually turning your computer off. This will be a reformat and a reinstall. If that happens again shortly, expect some failing hardware is causing this.